# Anyway to incorporate sudo into an SSH ProxyCommand?

Tags: ssh

At work, we have a SSH jump host that requires us to use `sudo ssh` to SSH into the destination host. Something like this:

```
ssh jump-host
sudo -u sshuser ssh final-host
```

I'm trying to incorporate this into a ProxyCommand or similar SSH config setup so I can just run `ssh final-host`, but I'm not sure how or if it's possible.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't integrate a remote `sudo` call into a `ProxyCommand` in *your* use-case, but you can -since [OpenSSH 7.6 (Oct 2018)](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.6)- use:

> #### RemoteCommand
>
> Specifies a command to execute on the remote machine after successfully connecting to the server. The command string extends to the end of the line, and is executed with the user's shell. Arguments to `RemoteCommand` accept the tokens described in the [TOKENS](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-6.2/ssh_config#TOKENS) section.

So, you can make an entry in `.ssh/config` like so:

```
Host finalhost
    RemoteCommand sudo -u sshuser ssh final-host
    RequestTTY yes
    Hostname jumphost

Host jumphost
     User jumpHostUser
     ... Other options for jumphost, if necessary
```

This works only for the terminal subsystem, therefore `sftp finalhost` will land you on *jumphost*, not *finalhost*. `git` and some other tools will not work with *finalhost*.

Comment: `HostName` doesn't seem to allow you to point to an alias (`jumphost` in this example), rather, it wants the actual host name there. At least that's what I'm seeing...

Comment: This works perfectly even using OpenSSH client built into Windows 10+. But the vscode remote plugin just lands in jumphost, most likely due to it not honoring the `RemoteCommand`

Answer (score -1):

why don't you have a relay script ?

On jump-host have a script `goto.sh`

```
sudo -u $1 ssh $2
```

on local host have a script `jump.sh`

```
ssh jump-host goto.sh my-ssh-user $1
```

then, from local host, just do

```
jump.sh final-host
```

this is assuming

- every local user have a different ssh-user on jump-host
- `goto.sh` is in your $PATH on jump host

Answer (score -1):

This requires that `nc` is installed on finalhost:

```
Host finalhost
  proxycommand sudo ssh jumphost ssh finalhost nc localhost 22
```

It `ssh`s to jumphost, then to finalhost, where it tunnels data to localhost's port 22, which is what the your `ssh` command then connects to.

Comment: This does not use sudo on jumphost...